# Sending SPARQL queries from C# using stardog: "cannot execute update query on read endpoint"

Tags: c#, sparql, dotnetrdf, stardog

as the title says i'm trying to create triples using SPARQL queries from visualstudio. Using the same SPARQL queries inside stardog studio works, but when i try to send them from visualstudio using the stardogconnector i get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'VDS.RDF.Query.RdfQueryException' occurred in dotNetRDF.dll
>   Additional information: A HTTP error (HTTP 400 Bad Request) occured while querying the Store.
>   Store returned the following error message: {"message":"Cannot execute update query on read endpoint"}
>   See aforementioned status line or inner exception for further details occurred

Here is the code:

```
StardogConnector stardog = new StardogConnector("http://localhost:5820", "dbtest", "admin", "password");
stardog.Begin();
string query = "INSERT DATA { <http://example/book1> dc:title \"test\"}";
stardog.Query(query);
stardog.Commit();
```

As i said, inserting the same query inside stardog studio gives the right result. The database is online, the connection works (password etc. is correct),...
I just don't know what the error means. Can anybody help? I don't find much online about this error.

Comment: THANK YOU for helping! 
stardog.Update(query);   did the trick

Comment: Please don't edit the question title with "SOLVED", instead upvote and/or accept an answer. Or in this case, since the solution is in a comment, post an answer yourself. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When `query` includes `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or other *write* action, you have to change [`stardog.Query(query);`](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/html/M_VDS_RDF_Storage_BaseStardogConnector_Query.htm) (which is read-only) to [`stardog.Update(query);`](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/html/M_VDS_RDF_Storage_StardogV2Connector_Update.htm) (which is apparently write-only).

Answer (score 1):

It appears that dotNetRdf sends all queries to the `/myDb/query` endpoint, however as of Stardog 5.x all SPARQL update queries must instead be sent to the `/myDb/update` endpoint. Official Stardog tools (Studio, stardog.js, etc.) were updated at that time.

Feel free to direct any other questions over at community.stardog.com.

Comment: [`.Query()`](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/html/M_VDS_RDF_Storage_BaseStardogConnector_Query.htm) does this, that's why there is an additional command [`.Update()`](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/api/html/M_VDS_RDF_Storage_StardogV2Connector_Update.htm)